# GDPR - Do I have to log user's IP after consent for a cookie?

Tags: gdpr

Do I really have to log a user's IP address and a timestamp after they consent to a cookie?

Log example: `20.05.2018 18:56:32 - 127.0.0.1 - Cookie accepted`

I don't even need (I'm not using it in any way) personal data like IP address in my website.

Comment: Why are you asking this here on Law?

Comment: Where should I ask about GDPR I thought GDPR = law section.
I'm not asking how to do it, I'm asking if I have to do it to comply with GDPR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

That is spelled out pretty clear in [Article 11](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-11-gdpr/).

In fact, if you want follow accepted data minimisation principles (and you should), you should *not* log *anything* about cookies at your or a third party's website.

Comment: And how do you want to prove user's consent?

Comment: Where (in the GDPR) do you see a legal requirement to *prove* that the user consented to receive a cookie?

Comment: Art. 5 (2) GDPR

Comment: Art. 82 (3) GDPR

Comment: It is the controller's responsibility to prove that he acted according to the GDPR. When a cookie consent is necessary then the controller must be able to prove that it happened. Otherwise the user can simply state that it does not happened and you are in trouble.

Comment: "Otherwise the user can simply state that it does not happened and you are in trouble."  Thankfully, this is *not* how the law works. To be in trouble, the user must be able to *prove* to the regulatory authority (RA) that your website is not cookie compliant. Simply claiming that he/she was not presented with an option to consent to cookies will not do if software to do so is obviously installed on the website and working as it supposed to work.

Comment: Neither of the to articles you cite say anything about logging. To comply with Art 5(2), the controller must demonstrate that software for cookie compliance is installed and works as it is supposed to work. Art 82(3) is about fines for not complying. As already stated in my answer, logging cookie consent is contrary to data minimisation principles required by the GDPR. AFAIK, no regulatory aithority (RA) has ever *objected* to this widespread practise of *not* logging cookie consent. *I* am not logging cookie consent. I have checked with my local RA that this is OK.

Comment: No, the controller have to prove to be compliant. burden of proof reversal

Comment: "No, the controller have to prove to be compliant." Obviously. The question boils down to what constitutes "proof": Installation of suitable software or ability to present an easily faked log? My point is that a litigious user will not be able to create "trouble" for the controller simply by claiming that he was never presented with a cookie consent form if it can be proved that software to present such form is in use.

Comment: I agree, when you can prove that the software was in use and presented to the user. My question was "And how do you want to prove user's consent?". I did not say that it have to be proven by logging. Nor did I say that you're not compliant when not having a proof. 

Of course, logs can be faked more easily than a signed paper. Nevertheless faking the "right" ip address that was really assigned to the user at a given time is not that trivial. It is also used in other cases for proof.

I still see the controller in trouble when he's not able to prove that the user gave consent.

Comment: Even if you would record the IP address, you still cannot prove user's consent, because you cannot prove the IP address belongs to a particular person. In particular when the user uses a mobile phone, he would be typically using a dynamic IP address issued by the mobile network operator, or he would be connected over wifi using an IP address shared by multiple users. In a similar question I [suggested](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/30639/18215) to use screenshots showing how your website works as a proof, that would also proof from which date your website is cookie compliant.